# Why some photos are not shown on my External hard drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, anti-virus, kaspersky

I have a Seagate external hard drive and I have a problem with it. The device contains many photos, videos, music... and I have a folder of photos, this folder contains the different extension of images, a while ago, it displayed correctly all existing photos but now some photos are not shown in this folder and when I used the Easeus Data Recovery Wizard tool, it displayed the photos that are not shown to me in the file explorer. (Note that the photos existed before and suddenly in a way that I do not know, they have disappeared).

How can I fix this problem??

What can I do to fix my external hard drive?

**Update:**

I think that there is a bad sector that was removed by the Kaspersky tool ( Kaspersky Antivirus have a tool that repairs bad sectors ), and all images that are under this bad sector removed. So in this case what can I do?

Comment: Why was vital information about your underlying problem removed from this question?

Comment: I would like to be more specific, for that I edited my question

Comment: You do know that "bad sectors" on a HDD cannot actually be repaired?

Comment: Is this true? but I found many methods that can repair bad sectors, maybe you mean physical bad sectors not logical???

Comment: Yes; of course I mean physical and the fact you have lost files indicates it's a physicals hardware issue rather than a logical one.  All you indicated was a "bad sector", if files are disappearing, that is an indication of your files being orphaned. chkdsk would confirm a serious problem, but I wouldn't do that without a sector by sector backup of the drive.

Comment: I have tried chkdsk before, but I didn't get any results and I got only a message that says "chksdk could not repair RAW format ( something like this )" , please note that my hard drive is encrypted with BitLocker